# ASP.NET MVC 2 - How to override an annotation for a single controller action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, annotations

I have a BaseController that all Controllers inherit from.  The CaseController has the [Authorize] annotation, so that all controllers require authorization.

But I've just realized that one single controller action must not require authorization.  How can I turn off [Authorize] for just that one controller action?

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Unleashed.Service.Interfaces;

namespace Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    [RequireHttps]
    public class BaseController : Controller
    {
    }
}
```

And the controller action is called via a POST from another site.  They authorize by passing a token.  They will not be authorized via forms authentication.

```
[Authorize=false] // doesnt compile
[Authorize(false)] // doesnt compile
public ActionResult DoSomething(string token, string data)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by creating a new controller that does not inherit from BaseController, and adding the action to that controller.  Now this one action does not require authorization, and all existing actions remain as is.